How do I create new objects under old objects in a drawing?
I have code that creates a first object and then a second object that lies on top of the first object.  The goal is to split the second object so that it does not overlap the first object. Simply put, so that the second object hides under the first object.
import win32com.client
import pythoncom

acad = win32com.client.Dispatch("AutoCAD.Application")
ms = acad.ActiveDocument.ModelSpace
doc = acad.ActiveDocument 

obj_1 = [[0.09, 0.98, 0.13, 0.98, 0.17, 0.97, 0.2, 0.94, 0.2, 0.91, 0.17, 0.88, 0.13, 0.87, 0.09, 0.87, 0.05, 0.88, 0.02, 0.91, 0.02, 0.94, 0.05, 0.97, 0.09, 0.98]]
obj_2 = [[0.1, 0.77, 0.2, 1.07]]

def create_lines(coords):
    for line_coords in coords:
        for i in range(0, len(line_coords)-2, 2):
            x1, y1 = line_coords[i], line_coords[i+1]
            x2, y2 = line_coords[i+2], line_coords[i+3]
            ms.AddLine(APoint(x1, y1), APoint(x2, y2))


create_lines(obj_1)
create_lines(obj_2)


Maybe it can be done with the shapely library, but I don't understand how yet.

The coordinates of your example don't match the graph (see here). Can you double check ?

@Timeless, already fixed

Why you have nested lists of 1 item ? Can you have more than 1 in your real dataset ?

@Timeless, Yes, there can be many lines everywhere. some will intersect with the lines of other objects, some will not.

@Timeless, In the future, it should work like this - https://prnt.sc/W48PKCGFo7F0

I posted an approach below but If it's only for visual purposes, there might be many simpler options, like playing with the z order for example.

IIUC and asssuming you have multiple coordinates per object, you can plot the difference of their unary_union :
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from more_itertools import batched # or itertools if >=3.12
from shapely import LineString, Polygon, unary_union
from shapely.plotting import plot_line

def create_lines(coords):
    return unary_union(
        [
            (
                Polygon(ls) if (
                    ls := LineString(batched(coo, 2))
                ).is_ring else ls
            ) for coo in coords
        ]
    )

lines1, lines2 = map(create_lines, [obj_1, obj_2])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 7))

plot_line(lines2.difference(lines1), color="w", add_points=False, ax=ax)
plot_line(lines1.exterior, color="w", lw=2, add_points=False, ax=ax)

ax.set(facecolor="#242c34", xticks=[], yticks=[])

plt.show()



what about this data - obj_1 = [[0.09, 0.48, 0.13, 0.48, 0.17, 0.47, 0.2, 0.44, 0.2, 0.41, 0.17, 0.38, 0.13, 0.37, 0.09, 0.37, 0.05, 0.38, 0.02, 0.41, 0.02, 0.44, 0.05, 0.47, 0.09, 0.48]]
obj_2 = [[0.14, 0.53, 0.16, 0.53, 0.18, 0.52, 0.19, 0.5, 0.19, 0.49, 0.18, 0.46, 0.16, 0.45, 0.14, 0.45, 0.12, 0.46, 0.11, 0.49, 0.11, 0.5, 0.12, 0.52, 0.14, 0.53]]
obj_3 = [[0.1, 0.27, 0.1, 0.57], [0.15, 0.27, 0.15, 0.57], [0.22, 0.27, 0.22, 0.57], [0.3, 0.27, 0.3, 0.57]]? desired result - https://prnt.sc/gwxIrE4BMlAe

Just one request - write the code so that the result is created on the autocad drawing like in my post

or the code should output at least the coordinates of the lines, by which I draw the drawing as in the result.

hey, timeless, are you here?
