How do I create drawing elements by levels?
Input data format:
obj_1 = [(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2), (...),...]
obj_2 = [(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2), (...),...]
etc.

https://pastebin.com/EiZZEeQR
The task is to find a way to create new objects under old ones according to the order in which the creation function is called. In this case, we start by creating a obj_1, then a obj_2, which will hide under the obj_1. Then the obj_3 is created, and consequently this object is hidden under the first and second objects.
Desired output data - coordinates of all lines for drawing the drawing

Maybe i need to use the shapely library, but I'm not sure.
The shape of an object can be absolutely any, so it is not quite correct to write code based only on circles, triangles and lines.

This seems to be duplicate question, you asked this twice already without much difference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78309870/how-to-create-new-objects-under-old-ones,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78298127/how-do-i-create-new-objects-under-old-objects-in-a-drawing

It seems you suggested creating a new post in this thread because the input and task has changed. I will delete the old post.

There are two steps in your problem: 1) parse the input to appropriate (shapely) objects. 2) overlay them, cutting the the features. The previous two posts by gave good suggestions for both of these steps.

@VictorSavenije, I'm not quite sure how exactly to do that. Can you show in code a minimal reproducible example with the new data form?

from itertools import chain

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from more_itertools import batched
from shapely import Point, LineString, Polygon, MultiPoint, MultiLineString
from shapely.plotting import plot_polygon, plot_line, plot_points

Declare objects like in file given by OP:
obj_1 = [(0.3931383333340818, 1.1771275460626884, 0.0, 

Parsing data into shapely objects:
shapely_objects = []
for obj in chain(obj_3, obj_1, obj_2):
    n = len(obj) / 3
    if n == 0:
        continue
    elif n == 1:
        geom = Point(obj[0])
    else:
        data = list(batched(obj, 3, strict=True))
        geom = LineString(data)
        if geom.is_ring:
            geom = Polygon(data)
    shapely_objects.append(geom)

Actual processing:
def overlay(geometries: Iterable[BaseGeometry]):
    """
    Overlay shapely geometries: cut away the part of shapes that are underneath others.

    First features in input will be underneath, last feature will not be cut.
    """
    result = []
    s = set()
    tree = STRtree(geometries)
    for idx, current_feature in enumerate(geometries):
        s.add(idx)
        overlapping_features = tree.geometries.take(list(set(tree.query(current_feature)) - s))
        cut = current_feature.difference(unary_union(overlapping_features))
        result.append(cut)
    return result

shapes_overlain = overlay(shapely_objects)

Visualization:
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8, 4), sharex=True, sharey=True)
for shape in shapely_objects:
    if isinstance(shape, Polygon):
        plot_polygon(shape, color="w", add_points=False, ax=ax1)
    elif isinstance(shape, LineString):
        plot_line(shape, color="w", add_points=False, ax=ax1)
    else:
        plot_points(shape, color="w", add_points=False, ax=ax1)

for shape in shapes_overlain:
    if isinstance(shape, Polygon):
        plot_polygon(shape, color="w", add_points=False, ax=ax2)
    elif isinstance(shape, (MultiLineString, LineString)):
        plot_line(shape, color="w", add_points=False, ax=ax2)
    elif isinstance(shape, (Point, MultiPoint)):
        plot_points(shape, color="w", add_points=False, ax=ax2)
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"shape: {shape}")


ax1.set(facecolor="#242c34", xticks=[], yticks=[])
ax2.set(facecolor="#242c34", xticks=[], yticks=[])
ax1.set_title("Normal")
ax2.set_title("Overlain")
plt.show()



for obj in shapes_overlain: print(obj) outputs objects of types shapely (POLYGON Z ((0.809375732802001 0.893536082170627 0...etc), how to output line coordinates in lists? ([0.809375732802001, 0.893536082170627, 0, ...etc)

Please search a bit on your own first, especially in the shapely documentation in this case as the example creates shapely objects, to output coordinates from geometries. https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html
The issue here is that you can't easily do this in general, because you might get polygons with holes in it.

Thank you so much for your help, but I have one last request. Can you edit the code so that it accepts data in this format - https://pastebin.com/7qrv9JYZ?

No. This is (again) a parsing question unrelated to overlaying shapely objects. You should try that on your own first. See that this data is in different format than your first data.
Moreover, this new data might be in a form you are not expecting: gliba_30_50 contains 5 seperate lines constituting a polygon-like shape.
